# I can't execute php artisan serve on linux

Tags: php, laravel, linux-mint

Whenever i try to execute php artisan serve command i get this error

> PHP Warning:  require(/home/mehdi/laravelOrig/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/mehdi/laravelOrig/artisan on line 18
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/mehdi/laravelOrig/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/mehdi/laravelOrig/artisan
>   on line 18

I did try some answers i found on google and here but it still wont work , am I missing something ? 
Thank you!

Comment: You just need to do `composer update`

Comment: Does the file actually exist?

Comment: No ,vendor/autoload.php doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all install composer on your system and type following command.

```
1) goto your project directory from command line
2) composer update 
3) php artisan serve.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer 
I ran into more problems when executing it , i screenshoted it for the sake of visibility
http://i.imgur.com/1RLzPJl.png

Comment: which PHP version you are using?

Comment: try this ```sudo apt-get install php-mbstring```

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-mbstring

Comment: i'm using php 7.3.2 , i did "sudo apt-get install php-mbstring" and it installed correctly , but i still have problems with composer update

Comment: try to install all dependent extensions before update composer like `sudo apt-get install your-pcakges-name`

Comment: Thank you all, i installed php 7.3xml and php-mbstring 
it fixed the problem.