# "php artisan serve" returns "Operation not permitted"

Tags: php, linux, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am currently trying to host a Laravel project (which works perfectly fine running locally) on a linux server (via ssh) in the cloud. I have uploaded all the project files and thought I could run `php artisan serve` on the server just as I could locally. This does not work and returns this output:

```bash
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Tue Oct 31 ... 2023] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Operation not permitted)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8001
[Tue Oct ... 2023] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8001 (reason: Operation not permitted)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8002
[Tue Oct ... 2023] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8002 (reason: Operation not permitted)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8003
[Tue Oct ... 2023] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8003 (reason: Operation not permitted)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8004
[Tue Oct 31 ... 2023] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8004 (reason: Operation not permitted)
...
```

I've tried the following stackoverflow solutions already, but none of them worked:

- [Unable to start laravel development server on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691609/unable-to-start-laravel-development-server-on-linux/) (Suggests restarting the "php artisan serve" process)
- [Artisan Error: Failed to listen on localhost:8000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900174/artisan-error-failed-to-listen-on-localhost8000#33560446) (Suggests checking if the specified port is available)
- [php artisan serve failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64356428/php-artisan-serve-failing) (Suggests changing the php.ini file)
- [I can't execute php artisan serve on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54983528/i-cant-execute-php-artisan-serve-on-linux) (Suggests updating composer to run artisan – this solution seems promising, but **I do not have root access on the server**)

Detailed Description of the Results:

- Restarting the "php artisan serve" process:
  There is no such process running.
- Checking if the specified port is available:
  The solution returns an error (`netstat: lnt: unknown or uninstrumented protocol`) and other than that I tried dozens of ports above and below 8000, so I do not think the port is a problem.
- Changing the php.ini file:
  There are many suggestions on what to change (variables_order, extensions, etc.) but none worked out for me.
- Updating composer to run artisan:
  Permission denied, as I do not have root permissions and cannot run sudo commands.
  (`Composer update failed: "/usr/local/bin/composer.phar" could not be written.     rename(/usr/local/bin/composer.phar): Failed to open stream: Permission denied`)

Another problem is that when searching for my exact Error I get no results on Google, so it seems like there is no solution online for "reason: Operation not permitted".

Is there another possible solution I could try or is Root Access a must have and I should move to another host?

*More Information:*

- *Composer Version: 1.10.26*
- *PHP Version: 8.1.21*
- *Laravel Framework: 8.83.27 (what it prints when i run `php artisan -V`)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `php artisan serve` should only be used locally for development purposes, as it use the PHP [built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), which is not meant for production.

> **Warning**
> This web server is designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

Nevertheless, you said you don't have root access on the server, so I guess you are using a shared hosting server. In that case, you are probably not allowed by your provider to launch your own web server, but you have to use the control panel provided by your provider to deploy your application.